# MemoryError in pd.DataFrame()

Tags: pandas, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I have a df with 2 columns and 5 million rows, all text (customer reviews of businesses).
`df.head()` produces:
[image]

`df.info()` shows that memory usage is only 120.3+ MB

I am trying to do topic modelling of `df['text']` using the gensim library. I attempt to create a document-term matrix (dtm) first and then perform latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA) as follow:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from gensim import matutils, models
import scipy.sparse

cv = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
data_cv = cv.fit_transform(df.text)
data_dtm = pd.DataFrame(data_cv.toarray(), columns=cv.get_feature_names()) #LINE THROWING MemoryError

data_dtm.index = df.index

tdm = data_dtm.transpose()

sparse_counts = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(tdm)
corpus = matutils.Sparse2Corpus(sparse_counts)

id2word = dict((v, k) for k, v in cv.vocabulary_.items())
lda = models.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=id2word, num_topics=2, passes=10)
lda.print_topics()
```

**Issue**: But the 7th line (pd.DataFrame()) throws the MemoryError  while I still have 60% of the machine memory free. Even when I repeat the operation on the first 100,000 rows of df, I get the same MemoryError.

Since this is topic modeling, I would rather analyze all the rows together, or at least analyze them in a few batches.

**Question** What is making Python run out of memory when converting `data_cv` to dataframe? How can I get past it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite possibly the `data_cv.toarray()` that's most-responsible for the memory expansion, by turning an efficient sparse representation into a full/dense array.

Try doing that step on a separate preceding line into a temporary variable, to check.

But if your end-goal is doing a Gensim LDA analysis, those steps  work well with tokenized text as input, so other actions (involving `CountVectorizer` and storing interim results or giant term-document arrays in Pandas data structures) may be superfluous.

For example (ignoring any stopword filtering):

```
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary
from gensim.models import LdaModel

tokenized_texts = [text_string.split() for text_string in df.text]
texts_dictionary = Dictionary(tokenized_texts)
texts_bows = [texts_dictionary.doc2bow(text_tokens) for text_tokens in tokenized_texts]

lda = LdaModel(corpus=texts_bows, id2word=texts_dictionary, num_topics=2)
```

**This still creates two giant copies of the `df.text` column in memory**, a list of `tokenized_texts` and a list of `texts_bows`, so it uses more memory than optimal. (The best practice for very-large corpora is to leave them on disk, and stream them item-by-item into the processing steps.)

But, it may use less than the giant dense `.toarray()` step, and never even creates not-strictly-necessary `CountVectorizer` or interim array and `DataFrame` objects.